# How to remove an element from an array state in React (Hooks)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of text inputs with the data coming from an array (state) containing URL's and given an index I wanna delete the respective element. I have this block of code where the `console.log` correctly shows the new array without the element that I removed, but for some reason on the page always the last input will be removed from the list (visually saying - image below).

```
const [videosList, setVideosList] = useState(videos.split(","))

const deleteVideo = (e) => {

    e.preventDefault()

    const index = parseInt(e.currentTarget.dataset.urlIndex)

    const removeFromVideosList = [...videosList]

    const newFromVideosList = {
        data: removeFromVideosList.filter((_, i) => i !== index)
    }

    console.log(newFromVideosList.data);

    setVideosList([...newFromVideosList.data])
}
```

...

```
{
    videosList.map((value, key) => {

        return (
            <Row key={key}>
                <Col xs={10}>
                    {inputUrl(value)}
                </Col>
                <Col xs={2}>
                    <a 
                        href="#" 
                        className="delete-video"
                        onClick={deleteVideo}
                        data-url-index={key}
                    >
                        <FaTrash />
                    </a>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        )
    })
}
```

Doesn't matter where I click, always the last input will be removed from the list (but the `console.log(newFromVideosList.data);` shows the new array correctly).

[image]

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here? Thanks!

EDIT1 - I have changed the way I was removing the element according to the suggestion of the guys here but still the same behavior (console.log is good but the last element is being removed by React):

```
const deleteVideo = (e) => {

    e.preventDefault()

    const removeFromVideosList = [...videosList]

    var index = removeFromVideosList.indexOf(e.currentTarget.dataset.url)

    if (index !== -1) {

        removeFromVideosList.splice(index, 1)

        console.log(removeFromVideosList);

        setVideosList([...removeFromVideosList])
    }
}
```

EDIT2:

```
{
    videosList.map((value, key) => {

        return (
            <Row key={`video_${key}`}>
                <Col xs={10}>
                    {inputUrl(value)}
                </Col>
                <Col xs={2}>
                    <a 
                        href="#" 
                        className="delete-video"
                        onClick={deleteVideo}
                        data-url={value}
                    >
                        <FaTrash />
                    </a>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        )
    })
}
```

Comment: array's index should not be used as key. that is the problem.

Comment: Yeah, index is coming correct for sure. On the console.log that I inserted there, the new array (without the element) is also correct, I can't understand why (visually saying only) the last element will be removed.

Comment: yeah, I just deleted my comment because what @AngelSalazar mentioned is more than likely your problem. Because the index is being used as the key, then React will not re-render certain elements quite as you expect because each element's key changes when its position in the array changes. Try introducing some other unique attribute to serve as the key instead (possibly the `xxxxxxxx` component of the video link)

Comment: Thanks guys, but still happening exactly the same thing. I'm not getting from the key anymore but from the .indexOf and didn't fix :\

Comment: I've updated my post with my last try

Comment: @AlexandrePaiva we were referring to changing the key for the `Row` and `a` components

Comment: @awarrier99 I've updated the post again, including these changes you mentioned... and still :\ I have no idea what's wrong, I've tried many different ways...

Comment: @AlexandrePaiva the issue is that the key you are providing is still dependent on the the index of the video within the array. The `key` needs to be set to something entirely independent of its array index. Can you include an example of what each video value looks like so I can better help?

Comment: Hi @AlexandrePaiva, I think you misunderstood the comment. They meant the react `key` attribute in your render. Your first `deleteVideo` function was fine, but when mapping the videos inside your render, you should use something else for your `key` (in your `<Row>` component). If the URLs are always unique, it could even be that. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't get it before. I was understanding it wrong. I've just replaced the <Row key={key}> to <Row key={value}> and worked. Thanks for your patience guys!!

Comment: @awarrier99 if you want you can add your answer so I can accept. Thank you too Bruno

Comment: @AlexandrePaiva no problem, and I just posted one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rendered `Row`s were keyed off of the array index, but instead they should be keyed off of something that is entirely unique to each value so that React correctly knows which element(s) to update. Something like:

`<Row key={value}>`

rather than

`<Row key={key}>` (where key is the index of the value in the array)

Answer (score 0):

{
    videosList.map((value, key) => {

```
    return (
        /*use key as something unique to each row except the array's index */
        <Row key={value.id}>
            <Col xs={10}>
                {inputUrl(value)}
            </Col>
            <Col xs={2}>
                <a 
                    href="#" 
                    className="delete-video"
                    onClick={deleteVideo}
                    data-url-index={key}
                >
                    <FaTrash />
                </a>
            </Col>
        </Row>
    )
})
```

}

Comment: Thanks man, it was almost that. Actually only "value" was enough to fix (I don't have "id" key on my array)